# Does PHP allow *.properties file as in Java?

Tags: java, php

Is there a way to use a *.properties file in PHP as you do in Java? I'd like to store some application-level constants in a properties or XML file and easily call them from throughout my code. Your guidance is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well it supports XML, you would probably have to provide a facility to read it in however, no idea if there is a library available.

Comment: You can include a file with property settings? An array perhaps. I'm not familiar with Java, but that's what it sounds like you're asking

Comment: I guess the XML reading facility is what I'm looking for, something easy to use and quick.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

PHP can natively load and parse `.ini` files using [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file).

You can also set up constants in an include file using `define()`.

If you're set on XML, look into PHP's XML functionality. The simplest solution is probably to use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml).

Comment: SimpleXML does not support that much of XML, so some tend to say that DomDocument is indeed better. A nice XML interface is provided by [FluentDOM](http://fluentdom.github.com/) but it's an external library. Not saying that SimpleXML won't work.

Comment: It'll probably be plenty for a properties file.

Comment: As I just found out `.properties` files do not contain any XML at all.

Comment: Down-voted because parse_ini_file says it no longer treats # as a comment, which is the normal way to do it in .properties format.

Comment: @Trejkaz Lame. OP needed a similar solution to a .properties file, not a .properties file parser. .ini files can serve that purpose in PHP.

Comment: @ceejayoz That isn't how the title reads, so naturally people who come here wanting an answer to the same question are going to downvote an answer which doesn't answer it.

Comment: @Trejkaz Considering this answer has 12 upvotes and just your downvote, that appears to not be the case.

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't see how that contradicts my claim. It just means that 12 people came here not looking for the thing mentioned in the title.

Comment: @Trejkaz It's also the question asker's **accepted answer**. This is my final comment here, I'm assuming you're just trolling at this point.

Comment: @ceejayoz Another false assumption, but yeah, this is getting nowhere.

Comment: I have a split Java/PHP application and I wanted to use the same properties file on both sides - if possible.  I was able to with this technique.  I lose the ability to comment my properties file, but I'm okay with that.  Too bad, PHP got rid of # as a comment.  If you want @ceejayoz, I can edit your response to reflect this.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use a PHP file containing an array to store data.
Example:

config.php

```
<?php 
return array(
    'dbhost' => 'localhost',
    'title'   => 'My app'
);
```

Then in another file:

```
$config = require 'config.php':
echo $config['title'];
```

Answer (score 7):

`parse_ini_file` doesn't have anything to do with `*.properties` files in Java environments.

I create this function, that does the exact same thing as its equivalent in Java:

```
function parse_properties($txtProperties) {
    $result = array();
    $lines = split("\n", $txtProperties);
    $key = "";
    $isWaitingOtherLine = false;

    foreach($lines as $i=>$line) {
        if(empty($line) || (!$isWaitingOtherLine && strpos($line,"#") === 0)) continue;

        if(!$isWaitingOtherLine) {
            $key = substr($line,0,strpos($line,'='));
            $value = substr($line,strpos($line,'=') + 1, strlen($line));
        } else {
            $value .= $line;
        }

        /* Check if ends with single '\' */
        if(strrpos($value,"\\") === strlen($value)-strlen("\\")) {
            $value = substr($value, 0, strlen($value)-1)."\n";
            $isWaitingOtherLine = true;
        } else {
            $isWaitingOtherLine = false;
        }

        $result[$key] = $value;
        unset($lines[$i]);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This function was first [posted on my blog](https://mufumbo.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/reading-java-style-properties-file-in-php/).

Comment: The link says "Warning! Domain mapping upgrade for this domain not found. Please log in and go to the Domains Upgrades page of your blog to use this domain." This looks like the right link: https://mufumbo.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/reading-java-style-properties-file-in-php/

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could perfectly put some configuration in a properties file and do the parsing yourself. But in PHP it's not the appropriate format todo so.

I would define some constants and put them in a seperate php config file (like config.php) and include this where needed.

Other options would be to actually put the configuration in a xml file and use a [xml library](http://be.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) the read it. [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) ([php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.yaml.php)) is also a popular option for simple readable configuration.

Comment: You say that `*.properties` files are "not the appropriate format to do so" in PHP. Why is that? Why should one avoid using the `*.properties` format, besides the fact that PHP natively supporting the `*.ini` format (which you - strangely - did not even mention alongside alternatives like XML and YAML)?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no PHP built-in functions to read and handle .properties files. If the application you wrote in PHP needs to read Java .properties files, you need to code your own solution by reading the file and create your own .properties parser.

Otherwise, as mentionned by other members here, you can store configuration information into a .ini file. PHP provides native functions to load and parse .ini files.

If you prefer the information is stored into a XML file with the PHP XML parser ([PHP Manual Function Reference XML Manipulation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)).

Personally, I prefer to store configuration / application constant values into an array. I created a Configuration class that handle configuration file.

There is an example here :

**Configuration file example (ex : config.php)**

```
<?php
    // Typical configuration file
    $config['database']['type']         = 'mysql';
    $config['database']['host']         = 'localhost';
    $config['database']['username']     = 'root';
    $config['database']['password']     = 'your_password';
    $config['database']['database']     = 'your_project';
    $config['date']['timezone']         = 'America/Montreal';
?>
```

**Class Configuration**

```
<?php
    class Configuration
    {
        protected $configuration;

        function __construct($filename)
        {
            // CFG_PATH : i.e --> define('CFG_PATH',dirname(__FILE__) . '/cfg/');
            require(CFG_PATH . $filename);
            $this->setConfiguration($config);
        }

        public function getConfiguration($configuration)
        {
            return $this->configuration[$configuration];
        }

        public function setConfiguration($configuration)
        {
            $this->configuration = $configuration;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Typical use example**

```
<?php

    // Your class definitions, variables, functions...

    function __construct() {

        $this->configuration = new Configuration(CFG_FILE);
        $this->set_Timezone($this->configuration->getConfiguration('date'));

    }

    private function set_Timezone($configuration)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set($configuration['timezone']);
    }

?>
```

**Other example (Controller and DAO)**

**Controller**

```
<?php

    protected function doPost() {
        ...
        $configuration = new Configuration(CFG_FILE);
        $dao = new DAO($configuration->getConfiguration('database'));
        ...
    }

?>
```

**DAO example**

```
<?php

    function __construct($configuration) {
        // Build DSN (Data Source Name) string 
        if ($configuration['type'] == 'mysql') {
            $this->dsn = '(type):host=(host);dbname=(database);charset=UTF8';
            $this->dsn = str_replace('(type)', $configuration['type'], $this->dsn);
            $this->dsn = str_replace('(host)', $configuration['host'], $this->dsn);
            $this->dsn = str_replace('(database)', $configuration['database'], $this->dsn);
            $this->options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'');
            try
            {
                $this->databaseHandle = new PDO($this->dsn, $configuration['username'], $configuration['password'], $this->options);
            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ... 
        }
    }

?>
```

If you use Spring framework in Java and you want a similar solution for messages.properties in PHP, you can adapt the same solution mentionned above. Of course, the behavior won't be the same as Java, but, with Locale class, you can create functions that handle messages/labels in your PHP application based on location where client is located.

With this kind of solution based on arrays, I think this will help you to define required values in your application and organize your configuration data as well. Of course, there is many other ways to achieve this, but I think is solution works.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP .ini files serve almost same functionality. There are simple methods to read constants from these files.

Further most of the PHP frameworks implement it with configuration files mostly with extension .php.

for example in cake php we have Configure class which provides  like Configure::read('VarName') and Configure::write('VarName',VarValue);

once written this can be accessed in the scope of file inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getLocale($file){
    $locales = array();
    $accessible = fopen($file, "r");
    if (!$accessible) return null;
    while (($line = fgets($accessible)) !== false) {
        $pos = strpos($line, '=');
        if (!$pos) continue;
        $name = substr($line, 0, $pos);
        $value = substr($line, $pos + 1, strlen($line));
        $locales[$name] = $value;
    }
    return $locales;
}
getLocale('lang/eng.properties');
```

Comment: Thanks, @MARKODY. That's a very clever way of doing it! Great job!