# Read .properties files using PHP

Tags: php, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does PHP allow *.properties file as in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900077/does-php-allow-properties-file-as-in-java)

How to read/parse .properties file using PHP?

Comment: file_get_contents(file_name);

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What is the format of the data in the file - or give an example.

Comment: admin = abc
password = 123
host = abc123

This is the content of the .properties file

Answer (score 10):

`.properties` files are usually used in `Java` platform. Its counterpart in PHP is `.ini` files. `.ini` files can be parsed natively by PHP using [`parse_ini_file()`](http://in.php.net/parse_ini_file). See this stackoverflow question: [Does PHP allow *.properties file as in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5900077/851432).

Still, if you would like to read and parse `.properties` files, you have to do that manually. A quick search on Google take me to the following result:

- [reading java-style properties file in PHP](https://mufumbo.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/reading-java-style-properties-file-in-php/) - Github [repository](https://gist.github.com/977771)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I've taken the sample code and update it with the various comment I've read around. (deprecation of split, bug fix)

I've removed the multiline support as I don't need it.

https://github.com/dev-mansonthomas/RedCrossQuest/blob/master/GCP/init_lib/common.sh

props "/home/somewhere/application.properties"