# Parsing .properties file into array

Tags: php, parsing

I am trying to create some sort of GUI for a server.properties file, which is for Minecraft, the file is laid out like this;

```
level-name: world
server-ip: 123.123.123
```

The file could also have stuff like ##properties.file etc etc on single lines, this could add to the confusion

So basically i need a way of splitting it out into a readable format

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does PHP allow \*.properties file as in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900077/does-php-allow-properties-file-as-in-java)

Comment: Wondering does not qualify here as a reason to ask. There is room between wondering and asking here so to say, it's commonly describben as "Homework", please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
$file_path = '/some/path/to/properties/file.properties';
$lines = explode("\n", trim(file_get_contents($file_path)));
$properties = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $line = trim($line);

    if (!$line || substr($line, 0, 1) == '#') // skip empty lines and comments
        continue;

    if (false !== ($pos = strpos($line, ':'))) {
        $properties[trim(substr($line, 0, $pos))] = trim(substr($line, $pos + 1));
    }
}
print_r($properties);
// -> Array
// -> (
// ->     [level-name] => world
// ->     [server-ip] => 123.123.123
// -> )
```

Comment: `$lines = file($file_path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);` is simpler.